# How wiring works when we autowire inside interface? What are the cons and pros?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have quite good understanding of DI in general. The only issue which puzzles me is it safe to autowire inside interface? When we autowire inside interface then essentially we are not transparently introudicing tight coupling as we mandate that such and such interface should have something injected inside so its implementation should too. I also heard that it may give headache for AOP and transactional annotations. To support question with example consider:

```
@Repository("userRepository")
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
```

That is traditional - no problems here. Just assume I refer to @PersistenceContext as to @Autowired which is practically the same except for JPA. Now consider another example where my head explodes.

Instead of injecting entityManger inside UserRepositoryImpl, we can inject it inside UserRepository.

```
public interface UserRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager em;

    User save(User user);
```

Please explain whether there are benefits of doing this and are there any traps I have to be aware.

The motivation is: if we code to interfaces then we should do it 100%. Yet when we do it(in the second approach), we enforce dependencies for other implementations not necessarily requiring the same dependencies in their implementations , what if I want to use jdbcTemplate in my other implementation? Of course you can retaliate with ORM native querying but that's not the point.

What I have shown is not interface dependency injection. Just upfront declaration. :-)
Thanks!

**I just realised I may have been wrong slightly - in interface it should be setter injection not shorthand notation, anyway the question remains the same.**

Comment: You already answered in your question: *Yet when we do it(in the second approach), we enforce dependencies for other implementations not necessarily requiring the same dependencies in their implementations*.

Comment: Interesting, I remember I've seen somewhere people using @Transactional inside interface which can be answered as service methods in most implementations are transactional? I also recall some AOP proxying problems when doing that. Thanks.